# Copy interior color to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have got table that has some cells colorized. I need to copy their value to another column. Here are my macros:

```
Sub exa()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("B:AJ")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each (cell).Interior.Color = RGB(138, 255, 132) in row.Cells

    Area.Offset(, 40).Value = Area.Value

  Next cell
Next row

End Sub
```

I am trying to find another approach to copy values of collorized cells. Now I am trying to do:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Integer
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:I8")


For Each Row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In Row.Cells
       If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(138, 255, 132) Then
      '  cell.Copy Destination:=Sheets("HMPB").Range("AU")
          Area.Offset(, 40).Value = Area.Value
       Next cell
Next Row

End Sub
```

There is something wrong with the string

```
(cell).Interior.Color = RGB(138, 255, 132) in row.Cells
```

This is what I need: [image: http://postimage.org/image/4sjvimv35/]

Comment: Sorry, I had loosed part of the first code, when I putted new approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the code going regarding the color:

```
For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.cells
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(138, 255, 132)
    Next cell
Next row
```

To get the effect that you need, the approach may be differently. However, I'm not sure if this is part of your question.

Comment: I had rewrite you code to my task, bit every time I am getting error with for loop. I had put it on top of my post, could you help me, I can't understand what's wrong

Comment: Well I don't really know what you need in its entirety, but the reason why your code bugs is because it is syntactically incorrect.